# Calculate conditional probability using groupby and shift operations in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I have a dataframe with patients and their visits and the presence of a disease in their left and/or right eye is labeled with {0,1} values (0 = not present and 1 = present). The dataset looks like this:

```
Patient   R L

P_1       0 1

P_1       1 1

P_1       0 1

P_1       0 1

P_1       0 1

P_2       1 1

P_2       0 1

P_2       0 1

P_2       1 1

P_3       0 0

P_3       1 1

P_3       0 0

P_3       0 1

P_3       1 1

P_3       0 1

and so on.....
```

How can I calculate, for example, the conditional probability of P(R=1 | L=1) using grouby and shift operations in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.groupby('L').R.mean()
```

gives

```
L
0    0.000000
1    0.384615
Name: R, dtype: float64
```

So the answer: `P(R=1|L=1) = 0.384`, and `P(R=1|L=0) = 0`.

Or if we want to get probability on patients as well:

```
df.groupby(['Patient','L']).R.mean()
```

gives:

```
Patient  L
P_1      1    0.2
P_2      1    0.5
P_3      0    0.0
         1    0.5
Name: R, dtype: float64
```

so, for example, `P(R=1|Patent=P_3, L=1) = 0.5`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I guess likewise for P(L=1 | R =1) and P(L = 1 | R = 0) . What about P(R=0 | L =1) and P(R = 0 | L = 0) or for same eye, i.e.  P(R=0 | R =1)?

Comment: `P(R=0|L=1) = 1 - P(R=1|L=1)`, so another subtraction. And `P(R=0|R=1)`???

Comment: P(R=0|R=1) in terms of what is the conditional prob for the same eye?

Comment: I think that P(R=1|L=1) is not the correct calculation to find the conditional because when the visits of one patient end and the visits of the next patient start, the transition of the event is taken into account among different patients